# Getting the DateModifed of a file using Stat() in Perl - Inappropriate I/O control operation

Tags: perl, stat

I'm attempting to read a file's datemodified value, but I've been unable to do so. I'm continually receiving "Inappropriate I/O control operation" errors. This is a windows directory structure that I'm attempting read. I've attempted to pass through the full file-path along with the file name ($outputFilePath."/".$files) to the stat() function ($! returns nothing in this case, program simply dies), as well as using a file-handle (below) with no results. Any help is appreciated.

```
chdir($outputFilePath);
opendir(my $dirHandle, $outputFilePath) or die "Cannot opendir $outputFilePath: $!";
my $files;
my $modTime; 
#print getcwd();
while($files = readdir($dirHandle)){
  if($files ne '.' && $files ne '..'){
    open(my $fileHandle, $files) or die "Cannot open $files: $!";
    $modTime = (stat($fileHandle))[9] or die "Cannot stat file $files: $!";
    print $files."-".$modTime."\n";
    close($fileHandle);
   }
}
closedir($dirHandle);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the following, which uses the [fileglob operator](http://books.google.com/books?id=qhV2XYSgTaMC&pg=PA92&lpg=PA92&dq=Perl%20glob%20angle-bracket%20operator&source=bl&ots=j_MkDNmS9n&sig=pMzrHnK2u2Prp-_HQatzbLyGLXA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2roMUZyzK5DSigKPvYCgBQ&ved=0CC0Q6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=Perl%20glob%20angle-bracket%20operator&f=false) to get the list of files in a directory, will assist you:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::stat;

my $outputFilePath = 'C:\Moodle\server\php';
chdir $outputFilePath;

print "$_-" . stat($_)->mtime . "\n" for <*>;
```

Partial output:

```
cfg-1292006858
data-1324925198
DB-1324925198
debugclient-0.9.0.exe-1198234832
...
tmp-1292006858
www-1292006858
xdebug.txt-1198234860
zendOptimizer-1324925193
```

The last line:

```
print "$_-" . stat($_)->mtime . "\n" for <*>;
        ^       ^         ^              ^^
        |       |         |              ||
        |       |         |              |+ - All files ( use <*.txt> to get only text files )
        |       |         |              + - glob angle-bracket operator generates list of file names in dir
        |       |         + - Get modification time
        |       + - Stat on file
        + - File name
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This method worked beautifully (I used a "while(glob("*.txt"))" statement to loop through the files). Thanks so much! Any thoughts as to why the other syntax was not working? Just curious - always looking to be a better coder.

Comment: @user2030881 - You're most welcome! Try `$modTime = (stat($files))[9] or die "Cannot stat file $files: $!";`, i.e., `stat`ing the file name instead of the handle--no need to `open` the file.  Worked just fine when that's done.

Answer (score 0):

`readdir` produces the list of filenames within the directory it is reading, i.e., without any path information.

So you'll need to open `"$outputFilePath/$files"` instead of `$files`.

Note that `stat` works on filenames as well as (or even better than) filehandles. So you could just call `stat` on the filename and save yourself the trouble of opening and closing a filehandle.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did mention in my submission that I attempted to use the full path in my stat call, and the program would still die ($! returns nothing rather than "inappropriate I/O control operation"). Any other ideas?